# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm new in spring boot and i tried to run my first project to create table in MySQL database, so i had an error message:

[in the image bellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOlv5.png)

So please if some could help me

Thank you

Comment: Please read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a response